# $M$ is a topological manifold if and only if $\partial M = \emptyset$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

This question is an exercise from Lee's book Introduction to smooth manifold. Given $M$ is a manifold with boundary ( that is $M$ is Hausdorff, second countable and every point of $M$ has a neighborhood homeomorphic to either an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or an open subset of $\mathbb{H}^n$); then $M$ is a topological manifold ( that is $M$ is Hausdorff, second countable and every point of $M$ has a neighborhood homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.) if and only if the boundary of $M$ is empty, $\partial M = \emptyset$.
Assuming the fact that a point of $M$ cannot be both a boundary point and an interior point I argue like this:

Suppose $M$ is a topological manifold, if possible let $\partial M \neq \emptyset$, let $p \in \partial M $ that is $p$ is in the domain of some boundary chart, but as $M$ is a topological manifold, $p$ is also in the domain of some chart homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is to say $p$ is an interior point of $M$ a contradiction.

**The confusion:** my professor says that this argument is not correct he say that you cannot guarantee that if $p$ belongs to the domain of some chart homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $p$ is an interior point. I could not follow his explanation ( his explanation goes something like this: the chart when considered as manifold with boundary are fixed, now if you choose another chart, it may not be those chart from that former case)

**question:** is my professor correct? if so why? or are my arguments ok?

Comment: If a point is in the boundary for one chart, it is in the boundary of all charts on which it is defined: this can be used to rigorously define the boundary of a manifold. If $x$ is in the interior of a chart, then there exists no chart $\varphi$ such that $\varphi(x)$ is in the boundary of $\mathbb{H}^n$, and $x$ does not belong to the boundary.

Comment: @Dldier That is my argument... I think but my professor is not happy

Comment: @Uncool your argument sounds totally right to me, maybe you need to explain a bit more why it is true, adding something like DIdier_ said.

Comment: Since you cannot reproduce your professor's argument, we can only guess what the issue is. Perhaps it is because you are starting by assuming the key thing he wants you to prove: that $p$ cannot be in the interior and on the boundary at the same time. That is, prove that if $p$ has a neighborhood homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$, then there is no chart carrying $p$ to the border of $\Bbb H^n$.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair I think I should do that

Comment: Please tell us which exercise you mean.

Comment: @Paul Frost That exercise which says if $M$ is a topological manifold then $\partial M= \emptyset$

Comment: @Uncool Doesn't it have a number? I guess readers do not want to study the whole book.

Comment: @Paul Frost yes it's exercise 1.39 , Introduction to Smooth Manifold (2nd edition).